# Is the mdoc macro set available on non-BSD systems by default?

Tags: man, bsd, compatibility

Are the MDoc macros, commonly used to create BSD manpages, commonly available on non-BSD systems (such as Ubuntu and other GNU Linux distros)? Is it safe to design manpages using them when writing cross-platform documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can probably use these macros without problems.

I looked on 3 sample OS's I have: ubuntu 14.04, debian 7.8, fedora 21, and they
all use the groff package to include the mandoc macros (though not the mandoc command)
and to provide a man page on them: mdoc(7).

I checked if there were any man pages installed actually using these macros with:

```
find /usr/share/man/man1/ -type f |
while read f;do if gzip -d <$f | fgrep '.Dd'; then echo $f; fi; done
```

and found several files, eg ftp(1), ssh-agent(1), ncal(1).  I tried the `man`
command on these, and they showed up correctly.

So, if most systems have groff installed they can read these man pages.  Anyone got a mac osx to try on?

Comment: They work on Mac OSX :) Thank you for your research!

Answer (score -1):

A typical UNIX system does not support the mdoc macros and if you like to write portable man pages, don't use mdoc.

Comment: Source? @meuh and myself have both proven this to be untrue.

Comment: Source? I have proven your claim to be false and as I am writing highly portable software that compiles and runs on nearly every OS, I know of many platforms where mdoc is not available.

Comment: Could you add a list of such platforms to your answer? Also, could you elaborate on `nearly every OS`? Is that nearly every OS, ever?

Comment: My software compiles and runs on at least 28 platforms (not counting different CPU types multiple times). BTW: All platforms that offer a real troff, typically do not support mdoc.

Comment: But mdoc != troff, it's usually groff. Mac just so happens to support groff.

Comment: Sorry to see that you seem to be miss-informed. The only mdoc package that works with troff was written by me (based on BSD-4.4). groff is definitely not troff and there are plenty of platforms that come with a real troff. Solaris, HP-UX, AIX, plan9 are some of them. Note that ditroff (the newer AT&T troff version) is OpenSource since a while and thus even OSS platforms can use troff instead of groff.